# How do I test if my laptop has suspended?

Tags: java

If I have a java application, how do I test if the computer has suspended? Like putting down the screen or clicking suspend.

Comment: What do you mean by "computer has suspended"?

Comment: When your computer is suspended, how you can run java application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition almost your computer does nothing when it's suspended. The CPU doesn't run, all memory is flushed out to disk. So nothing is running, your program won't do anything until the computer wakes up again, at which point it starts running again like nothing happened.

You could have the program cache a timestamp in a thread every minute or so. Then compare that with the previously cached timestamp. If there's a significant difference (more than seconds) between the found difference and the expected difference, something like a suspension probably happened (though in theory the thread might have been delayed by other things, sleeping only guarantees minimum sleep time, not maximum).